# Are RVs in the scope of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have an older motorhome that I want to maintain myself. Are questions about that vehicle appropriate for Mechanics SE? Here are some examples to consider:

- Why don't my house batteries get charged by my alternator?
- How to diagnose a propane furnace that won't ignite?
- How often should I refresh the roof sealant?
- No fuel is coming to the generator; why? (A play-within-a-play!)
- Remote start switch for the generator works, but switch on the unit does not.

A class A motorhome *is* a vehicle, but it's also a house (plumbing, HVAC, lighting, kitchen) and a boat (deep-cycle batteries, generator, water tanks), so some of those questions belong on [DIY SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) and [Boat SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4136/sailing?referrer=Me50XCzwyjqB49QQOgt7xA2).

Comment: Also related: http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/31/are-boat-trailers-on-topic-for-this-site

Answer (score 3):

There are (currently) *three* major areas of expertise covered on this site:

- Auto (vehicle) mechanics
- [Auto Body Work](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/are-body-repair-questions-on-topic-for-this-site)
- [Performance Engineering](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/are-body-repair-questions-on-topic-for-this-site)

The criteria I would use for all these questions is **"Would I bring my [RV, ATV, trailer, boat, jetski, snowmobile, golf cart] to one of these experts to resolve my problem?"** If the answer is "yes", it should be on topic:

- Batteries/Alternators
- Body Work
- Fuel Systems
- Engines, Drivetrain, Brakes, Maintenance, etc.

For the more home-y aspects of running and operating a motorhome, I'm not sure you will find the expertise you need here. Questions about furnaces, kitchens, plumbing, furnishing, trim, and the like are probably better asked on the [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Class C that I maintain myself and would like to think any question pertaining to the chassis is in scope.

Questions about "hotel services" (water, heat, AC, etc), I would be willing to answer personally...

Since I doubt there will be enough buy in for an RV SE I would like to discuss RV related stuff here.

Comment: There are a number of active message boards on RVs that are full of good information, carefully concealed. Getting those folks on an RV SE would be awesome, but as we know by now, making a successful SE site is non-trivial.

Comment: That's my experience as well.  My "user group" of fellow Lazy Daze owners are very good at documenting their experiences (via yahoogroups...) but I don't know if they could handle a SE style site.