# Are boat trailers on-topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example, how to wire a boat trailer so it will tolerate salt water, or replacing hub bearings. There's no motor but this is closely related to what you find in a car.

Answer (score 6):

A boat trailer is, essentially, an accessory to a vehicle. So as long as the question relates to the operation and maintenance as part of the vehicle — i.e. something you might reasonably expect an auto mechanic to work on (wiring, wheels, maintenance, like you said) — it sounds sufficiently on topic to me.

Answer (score 4):

I would find any trailer to be on topic with this site.  You have to deal with tires, brakes, bearings, axles, lights, wiring, and proper setup with a towing vehicle and such.  There are lots of maintenance and repair questions that would fit right in with similar answers to car/truck parts just with trailer specific instructions or things to consider.

This has some relation to the RV question: [Are RVs in the scope of this site?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/are-rvs-in-the-scope-of-this-site)

Answer (score 4):

Trailers in general should be on topic here if the question is relevant to the electrical or mechanical operation and or repair.

Unless of course you are going to be [programing on the boat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19487#19487) while it's on the trailer, if so it clearly belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Unless of course you are going to be programing on the boat ...." . wow . =D