# Regarding off-topic questions and the divide between "mechanics" and "motor vehicles."

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, user-interface

There have been a lot of questions regarding "Are XYZ questions on-topic for this site?"

When this beta first started, the sub-domain was "garage" and now it's "mechanics." A bicycle mechanic stumbling on to the site through Google might see the "mechanics" word in the URL and start asking questions about bicycles, only to be downvoted into oblivion because this site doesn't target bicycles as they do not have a motor, but they could technically be described as a vehicle.

A post about boat trailers presents the same issue. My boat trailer has wheels and an axle and I can hook it up to a vehicle, but it's not a motor vehicle in itself. So is such a question valid? It could be, depending on the topic (electrical, towing capability, etc.).

Taking that into account, in my opinion, the title of the site and the subdomain clash a bit. The more questions that get asked like the examples above, the more the knowledge-base we're contributing to becomes polluted and confusing. If the questions and content on the site are going to stem out into vehicle peripherals or other mechanically-involved activities, perhaps the title of the site should be broadened.

Does anybody else feel the same way?

**TL;DR**: I don't like the title of the site compared to the sub-domain name and the content its housing.

**EDIT**: Would the downvoter(s) care to explain why they downvoted?

Comment: I don't know who down-voted, but I've countered it for you.  This is definitely a good question, and an issue that needs to be discussed before this site progresses too much further, as it helps to define the scope of the site.  Perhaps the down-vote was because the voter likes the site title as-is, but the question of "How many different 'vehicles' are we covering here?" does need some answering.

Comment: +1 Good question indeed.

Answer (score 3):

The scope of this site may evolve over time, but there are (currently) *three* major areas of expertise covered on this site:

- Auto (vehicle) mechanics
- [Auto Body Work](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/are-body-repair-questions-on-topic-for-this-site)
- [Performance Engineering](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/are-body-repair-questions-on-topic-for-this-site)

The criteria I would use for all these questions is **"Would I bring my [car, truck, motorcycle, RV, ATV, trailer, boat, jetski, snowmobile, bicycle, skateboard, golf cart] to one of these experts to resolve my problem?"** If the answer is "yes", that's a pretty strong indication that it is on topic.

Comment: add "generator" to that list

Comment: Your link to performance engineering is currently broken: it's to the autobody meta question.

Comment: What about questions that require the same skillset, but aren't vehicle-oriented? For example, repairing a 2-stroke lawnmower engine.

Comment: @AlexFeinman: I haven't seen any questions along those lines, but if you have one, either try posting it or ask if it is on topic in a meta post.

Comment: Okay. Someone on another site preemptively *didn't* ask it here because they thought it wouldn't be.